# In Android, for Alarm Manager, SystemClock,elapsedRealTIme() works but alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis doesn't work

Tags: android

I am trying to make the schedule notification in android even though there is no internet connection. I tried and success for SystemClock but not for Calendar.
My code is :

```
AlarmManager alarmManager;
Intent alarmIntent;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Splash.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

This not working. But the following line is working fine. Its triggering in every 30 sec of time.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

I want my apps to trigger every 8:00 AM. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. While setting the second in calendar we have to use two digit number. I solved this question by using following code.

```
alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 08);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
```

and while calling i used like :

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), getInterval(), pendingIntent);
```

and set the interval method of one day so that it wake up always at 8AM.

```
  private int getInterval(){
    int days = 1;
    int hours = 24;
    int minutes = 60;
    int seconds = 60;
    int milliseconds = 1000;
    int repeatMS = days * hours * minutes * seconds * milliseconds;
    return repeatMS;
}
```

Comment: thx @paudel.sulav pupvoted for `setInexactRepeating` and `getInterval`

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html